# Getting electric power to a pivoting front door

Tags: power

I have a front door which I want set up with electronic unlocking.  Ive ordered a compatible motor for my system which requires 12v DC plus a separate 12v pulse to operate the mechanism.  This all fits inside the door.  The problem is how to get power to the motor because the door is pivoting, so there are no hinges. I don't want to have cables showing so I plan to drop power from above to the pivot point. My worry is how to drop cables that won't pinch when the door opens or closes.

I looked into pancake slip rings but can't find anything suitable. The door is held in place by a solid spindle about 2cm in diameter, the top of the door has a 1cm gap to the frame and the door is about 10cm in depth.

Any ideas.  I've attached  a photo.[this is looking along the top of the door](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgS9g.jpg)

Comment: Don't all (most doors) pivot; is it important to use that word? Is there a subtlety here that I may have missed? Don't hinges provide a pivot point? Maybe a diagram will explain? The picture might as well be taken on Mars as far as I can tell.

Comment: A horizontal pivot eh? Use a [curly cord](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcSQ7CN4WC11Tzjir-jNGRjASKCNbyHeK6fbb-fLArnv87r-v-CtgGqSCDCchUItkQqdwjV09XjRRq7VQDADMtslO2mjH3JQWS9OibDVlAjld2O3KMcg6fg-&usqp=CAc).

Comment: Sorry just uploaded another photo.  A pivot door rotates on a spindle at the top and the bottom. The photo is not rotated!

Comment: It sure looks rotated.

Comment: @jules_bike If you click the link to the photo, it looks like the door rotates around a horizontal axis (like a catflap). Sometimes EXIF rotation data doesn't work out.

Comment: Cant you fit the locking mechanism on the frame instead of the door?

Comment: Since the door has a limited rotation angle (say 270 degrees instead of consecutive rotations), you can have a pin machined and have the cable go through the pin and into the door. The cable can easily deal with being twisted 270 degrees.

Comment: Jules, there's an image upload button on the editor toolbar so you can insert the image in your post and we don't all have to follow a link. The photo looks rotated to me. You can verify the rotation before saving the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer to how to make the cable pass without beeing visible, but I have a few alternatives that also get to "nothing visible" in the end :

1. Putting the locking mechanism in the wall instead of in the door : no moving electronics, no wires having to rejoin the door.
2. Wireless energy transmission : something similar to wirless mobile phone charging : you have the energy emeter just above the door, and the receiver in the top of the door. The most basic way would just be 2 coils of wire one next to the other (placed in paralel in the geometrical sens).
3. Having some contacts only when the door is closed (using som springs for exemple).

For solutions 2 and 3, you will probably get no power when the door is open, so you will need to add a small battery.

4. Just but a "big" battery into the door, and change it once in a while (or recharge it in place). NB : take care to add some kind of alarm when the battery is nearly empty, but in some way that doesn't empty too much more the battery (for exemple on bip each 10 minutes if you can hear it from the living room)

Comment: @jules_bike - assuming your locking mechanism requires a pulse to unlock, then this suggestion #3 of having contacts which only close when the door is closed seems like a good idea. If the door is open there will obviously be no contact - but in that case you also don't need to unlock it, because it's already open...

Comment: @sandro the locking mechanism is a motor that pulls in the 3 latches for a couple of seconds so you can open the door then releases them.  So it needs power when the door is open as well as closed.  The big  battery option a possibility but I still need to find a way to pulse the motor but that only happens when the door is shut so a spring could work.

Comment: Yes, but you can have a small battery you charge each time the door is closed, and that provides enough energy for the short time the door is open

Comment: why do you need to release the latches when the door is open?

Comment: @sandro I've set up the door with spring electric contacts so there is power when the door is shut.  I now need to add a battery to release the door catches when the door is open.  I have 12v, ground and pulse going to the door.  Can I just wire in a 12v NiMH battery in the door, it will get a 12v current when the door is shut, is that a problem?

Comment: It should be possible to plug directly the 12V NiMH battery, but it requieres a few precautions/checks :
1) check that 12V is a correct state of charge (ie that at 12V your battery is "full enough", without taking the risk of being in the region where voltage drops again when overcharging
2) either you have to ensure that the voltage is never much bellow 12V, or you have to limit the charging current (either by a 12V supply with current limiter functionnality, or by adding a resistor between battery and supply) :the goal is to keep charging current within the specs of your battery.

Comment: @Sandro Thanks, the 12v supply is in fact 13.3v I just checked with a meter.  I don't understand what you mean by the voltage drop from overcharging.  Does a 12v battery pack have any form of battery management built in?  If not could you please  explain what circuit I could create.  I think my wife will kill me if I set fire to the front door

Comment: For the voltage drop : NiMH charging is a bit "strange" : at the end of charging, the voltage goes down (it's one of the ways NiMH chargers know when t stop charging). I suggest you read this article : https://www.disk91.com/2016/technology/hardware/lets-play-with-nimh-battery/

Comment: Most 12V NiMh battery packs do NOT include battery management system, and NiMh is not the simplest type of battery to do some "manual" charging. If you want to use NiMh, I would suggest you ask a new question (liniking to this one for background), so that people with more experiance in NiMh batteries can give you more accurate instructions.

Otherwise, buy yourself something of the shelf (battery + charger), making sure it is intended for "floating" operation (ie permanently connected).

Comment: @sandro thanks, I may have to change to lithium, NiMh are smaller so my preference. I will try a other  post to ask a out NiMh as you recommended.  If I went with Lithium would this be easier?

Comment: @Jasen to answer your question, the door is designed to self close but if the latches are pulled in it just bounces and you need to push it to get the power back into the motor which then releases the latches.

Comment: Lithium batteries have simpler charging curves, but require more protection (because if mishandled, there is a far bigger risk of catching fire). I think the simplest would be leaded batteries (but they are far more voluminous). Best ask a question about which battery technology is bet suited and how to implement it

Comment: If it bounces you need to adjust the closer.