# NiMH battery management

Tags: battery-charging, load, nimh

This follows on from a post I made about my front door (link at bottom of this post).

In essence I have a door with a 12 V motor in it, which is activated by a 12 V pulse. The power supply is only available while the door is closed, and I need a battery solution to release the door catches when the door is open.

I've bought a NiMH 12 V battery pack which I can fit into the door, but this would be in line with the 12 V power when the door is shut.

I need some help with avoiding overcharging this battery. Is there a simple circuit which would power the door, and safely charge the battery?

[Getting electric power to a pivoting front door](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/604078/getting-electric-power-to-a-pivoting-front-door)

Comment: What do you know about the 12 volt source? Does the voltage read higher than 12 volts when the door is closed and the battery would be connected to the charger?

Comment: Multi-chemistry battery charging ICs are cheap and easy, but you'll need something that can bump that 12V up too.

Comment: @SystemTheory the power supply is putting out 13.31v without the battery, I haven't received the battery yet so can tell if that would drop.

Comment: @vir if this is enough voltage where would I source  an IC  and what would it be called.

Comment: From Digikey, Mouser, etc.  You're looking for a Ni-MH or, more likely, multi-chemistry battery charging IC plus whatever other components are called out in the datasheet (probably a few passives, a transistor, and a thermistor).

Comment: A voltage cutoff charger would probably charge a 10 cell NiMH pack up to 1.4 volts per cell so the pack would be fully charged at 14 volts. The nominal pack voltage is 1.2 volts per cell so 10 x 1.2 = 12 volts nominal. In your application the 12 volt pack will not get a full charge from 13.1 volts, however, it may not need a full charge to function for short periods of time, and it may be possible to just use a trickle charger with series diode and current limiting resistor. I cannot find a good reference circuit maybe others have more experience to offer. Trickle charge may be about 1/40 C.

Comment: @vir thanks hopefully they can put something together for me it's become a bit more complicated than I expected!

Comment: @SystemTheory I wanted to avoid running a secondary power supply to the door just for charging.

Comment: You can use a boost converter to raise the voltage to whatever you need for the charging circuit, just don't overcurrent your supply or wiring.

Answer (score 2):

NiMH have two interesting peculiarities in this regard - one that makes life harder and another that makes everything dead simple.

NiMH cells actually **lower** their voltage at the end of charge. See e.g. [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8744/voltage-input-for-charging-nimh-batteries).

This is what quick chargers use as an end-of-charge signal. The same is rather not useful when charging 10S battery - a small disballance between cells completely hides the end of charge signal.

On the other hand, modern NiMH cells and batteries are absolutely tolerant to constant overcharge. If you are OK with the lower efficiency of the whole thing, you can just wire them to charge permanently with C/20 or C/40 current.

Comment: So I can just have them plugged in and they will never overcharge but when they are full they will lower voltage by some amount which might not be enough to power the motor.  I guess that would be worth trying.

Comment: The voltage lowering at the end of charge is minimal, you need a precise equipment to measure it. The motor will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this video for a simple NiMH charge circuit:

https://youtu.be/z-fEVy8qblw?t=144

He is using 12 volt source to charge 5 NiMH cells in series.

In your application the source voltage Vs = 13.1 volts. It will have an internal source resistance Rs which is unknown. The 10 cells in series have an internal resistance which changes with the State of Charge (SoC).

In your application the batteries might take a trickle charge current through the diode with or without a current limiting series resistor without overcharging but most likely the 12 volt NiMH pack will not fully charge. If it must discharge high amounts of current for long periods of time this would impact application performance. But if it only puts out energy in short bursts and can get a trickle charge for long periods of time then a basic charge circuit like this might suit your application.

Comment: I watched the video but he just had a resistor I didn't see how a diode fits into the circuit

Comment: He mentions the LED in series which is a light emitting diode. This could be a standard diode and is typically included for a basic trickle charge circuit. I am only familiar with a battery powered hand vacuum (dust buster). When the charger jack is plugged in, and the power switch is off, the wall wart charges the battery through a diode and current limit resistor. When the switch is turned on it disconnects the charge circuit and connects the brush motor in series with the battery. In your application it is not clear how the battery will connect to the charger and the load.